# react native linking custom fonts after removing react-native link

Tags: react-native

before react-native 0.70
I used the following configuration

```
//file react-native.config.js
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/aaa', './src/assets/fonts/bbb'],
};
```

and just calling

```
react-native link
```

it handles the linking job now
I'm getting `error: unknown command 'link'`
how to do the same job?

Answer (score 1):

this was removed react-native link after 0.69  i believe
you can use the following it works

```
 npx react-native-asset
```